# Como puedo recuperar un dato obtenido con ajax, dentro de una promesa done ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Con esta función lo que pretendo es poder crear y guardar un producto woocommerce desde el frontend e inmediatamente agregarlo al carrito, pero el dato response.data.prod_id no sé como pasarlo al promise done que se ejecuta inmediatamente. Les muestro parte del código para que vean si me pueden dar una luz:

```js
// Código editado con solución propuesta por Marcos, funciona perfectamente

var data = {
      action: 'save_simple_product',
      security : savesimpleproduct.security,
      formdata: form_data,
      attributes: attr_formatted,
      custom_attributes: cus_attr_formatted,
      categories: categories_formatted
    };

    $.post(savesimpleproduct.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
      if(response.success) {
        $('.apf-modal .apf-loading-section').hide();
        $('.apf-p-name span').append('<b><a href="'+response.data.permalink+'">'+response.data.prod_name+'</a></b>');
        $('.apf-modal .apf-modal-content .apf-modal-result').show();
        console.log(response);
        return response;            
      }
      else {
        $('.apf-modal .apf-loading-section').hide();
        $('.apf-modal .apf-modal-content .apf-modal-result-error .apf-modal-main section p').html(response.data.description);
        $('.apf-modal .apf-modal-content .apf-modal-result-error').show();
      }

    }).done(function(response){          
         $.ajax({
         url : wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
         type : "POST",
         data: {
           'action': 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',
           'product_id': response.data.prod_id,
           'quantity': 1
         },
         success: function(data2){
            window.location.href = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
         },
         error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + " entró aquí: " + xhr.responseText);
         }
         });       
     });
```

De antemano les agradezco cualquier muestra de apoyo.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Con la función ya se puede agregar un producto desde el frontend y la parte del código de agregar al carrito funciona si le defino un id de producto estático que ya exista, pero no dinámicamente como pretendo que funcione.

Comment: Hola Melvin, no veo ningún `.then`. ¿Podrás [edit] tu pregunta y agregar esa parte del código?

Comment: Perdón, era done, ya edité la pregunta con la corrección, gracias Marcos.

Comment: ¿probaste poniendo `return response;` dentro del `callback` de `$.post`?

Comment: Marcos, justamente era eso, ya me funciona el código. Te agradezco mucho tu valiosa ayuda. Saludos.